# Hide or remove the quantity field from WooCommerce Product filter in product-category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Every time I click on a category, it directs to product-category/name_of_ category page. I have a sidebar that displays filters for products in that category.
By default, it shows the quantity of product that match the filters. I want to remove that quantity.

Please guide me. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with [WOOF by Category](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woof-by-category/), which have the ability for this

Comment: if i don't want to use this plugin, is there any code to use in function.php ?